# Composición de imagen y gráfico en R

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

Que paquetes hay en R con los que pueda hacer un gráfico similar a este (el del dolar)? Tengo un gráfico con ggplot, usando geom_area.

[image: Valor y oferta de billetes de $1]

Comment: Jon, este es un sitio en español. Si pudieras [edit] tu pregunta para evitar que sea cerrada o puesta en espera, seria muy bueno.

Comment: Hey Jon, this is a spanish site. Would you please edit your question and translate it? Otherwise, it could probably be put on hold or be close.

Comment: @Kenny ya está. Gracias!

Comment: Tiene muy buena pinta esta pregunta, que curioso... Doy voto arriba por si alguien sabe, podría ser divertido el uso de esta idea..

Comment: Si consultas en siguiente [link](http://tiramisutes.github.io/2015/10/03/multiple-R.html) podrás ver múltiples ejemplos de como superponer dos gráficos

Answer (score 6):

Al menos hasta dónde conozco `ggplot` no tiene ninguna forma de aplicar una imagen a un área, es posible, si, colocar una imagen de fondo pero sobre toda la superficie. Tampoco he visto paquetes que permitan hacer algo así.

Pero hay un truco para hacer algo como lo que preguntas. Es cierto que tiene una limitación, que es, que no aplica a la imagen vectorial de `ggplot` sino que lo hace sobre la versión gráfica o de mapa de bits, pero teniendo en cuenta que normalmente los `plots` termina exportándose a imágenes, no pareciera ser muy limitante.

En primer lugar necesitaremos [Imagemagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), en R existe el paquete [Magick](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html) que empaqueta la gran mayoría de las herramientas del primero, pero no es tan flexible, o al menos no pude profundizar mucho en las opciones. Te voy a mostrar una prueba de concepto, está elaborada bajo Linux, pero con algunas modificaciones debiera correr en otras plataformas sin problemas.

Supongamos que tenemos el siguiente gráfico de área:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para generar el gráfico, simplemente, este es el código:

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(
    sex=factor(rep(c("F", "M"), each=200)),
    weight=round(c(rnorm(200, mean=55, sd=5),
                   rnorm(200, mean=65, sd=5)))
)

plot1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=weight)) +
    geom_area(stat = "bin", fill = "lightblue", color="darkblue")+
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(weight)),
               color="blue", linetype="dashed", size=1)
```

La idea es "sobreimponer" sobre el área, una imagen cualquiera, por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Generamos un nuevo plot con un color distinto

Mas adelante veremos para que, simplemente modificamos el color del área del plot original, por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código:

```
plot2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=weight)) +
    geom_area(stat = "bin", fill = "red", color="darkblue")+
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(weight)),
               color="blue", linetype="dashed", size=1)
```

Ambos `plots` los salvaremos en dos archivos. Está imagen la vamos a convertir en su versión negativa usando la herramienta `convert` de ya mencionado [Imagemagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Generamos una mascara

Si combinamos la imagen inicial, con su versión "negativa", obtenemos una imagen en blanco, cómo cuando sumamos 1 con -1. Ahora, en éste caso la imagen negativa, es ligeramente distinta de la original, difiere en el color del área, entonces al combinar ambas, lo que ocurrirá es esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Casi hemos generado una máscara, nos falta convertirla a blanco y negro y hacer nuevamente su versión negativa, algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Pegamos una imagen determinada a la mascara

Lo siguiente es combinar la máscara con la imagen que queremos "pegar" al área, para esto, primero que nada debemos ajustar nuestra imagen al tamaño de la gráfica, luego sobreimponer la imagen y configurar el área negra como color transparente (o canal alpha para ser más exactos), algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora está más clara la idea, lo último:

#### Combinamos el `plot` original con la máscara final

Simplemente combinando ambas "capas", terminamos por llegar al resultado final:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo esto, haciendo uso de la herramienta `convert`, en Linux suele venir ya instalada y accesible desde el `path`, en Windows, puedes descargarla y configurar el path a la misma. El código completo sería algo así:

La rutina principal:

```
#' Agregar una imagen en cualquier área de un ggplot
#'
#' Permite sobreimponer una imagen sobre cualquier área de un ggplot
#' Funciona a partir de dos gráficas idénticas pero que solo difieren en el color 
#' del área. 
#' @param imgmagick_path Path a la herramienta imagemagick (solo si no está en el path)
#' @param area_img_file Path al archivo de la imagen a incorporar
#' @param out_file Path y nombre del archivo final a generar
#' @param plot1 La versión 1 del plot
#' @param plot2 La versión 2 del mismo plot (solo debe ser distinto el color del área)
#' @param width Ancho del gráfico final (en units)
#' @param height Altura del gráfico final (en units)
#' @param units Unidade para determinar el tamaño de la imagen
#' @param dpi Reolución (dots per inch)
#' @export

add_image_to_color <- function(imgmagick_path = NA, 
                               area_img_file, 
                               out_file, 
                               plot1, 
                               plot2, 
                               width=20, 
                               height=10, 
                               units=c("cm"),
                               dpi=300){

    plot_file <- tempfile(pattern="plot_", fileext=".png")
    plot_file_negate <- tempfile(pattern="plot_negate_", fileext=".png")
    mask_file <- tempfile(pattern="mask_", fileext=".png")
    area_file <- tempfile(pattern="area_", fileext=".png")

    convert <- ifelse(!is.na(imgmagick_path),file.path(imgmagick_path, "convert"), "convert")

    # Salvamos las dos versiones de los plots    
    ggsave(plot_file, plot = plot1, scale = 1, width = width, height = height, units = units, dpi = dpi)
    ggsave(plot_file_negate, plot = plot2, scale = 1, width = width, height = height, units = units, dpi = dpi)

    # Negar imagen
    cmd <- paste(convert , plot_file_negate, "-negate", plot_file_negate)
    system(cmd)

    # Flat: me quedo solo con el area
    cmd <- paste(convert, plot_file, plot_file_negate, "-compose LinearBurn -composite -colorspace gray -auto-level -negate", mask_file)
    system(cmd)

    # Largo y ancho del plot
    cmd <- paste0(convert, " ", plot_file, ' -format "%wx%h" info: ')
    pplot_dim <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(system(cmd, intern = TRUE), "x"), as.integer))

    # Redimensiono la imagen del area
    cmd <- paste(convert, area_img_file, "-resize", paste0(pplot_dim[1],"x",pplot_dim[2], "!"), area_file )
    system(cmd)

    # Combinar capas para armar el area con la imagen y el fondo transparente
    if (Sys.info()[['sysname']] == "Linux") {
        cmd <- paste(convert, "-composite", area_file, plot_file, "\\( -blur 1x65000 \\)", mask_file, out_file)
    } else {
        cmd <- paste(convert, "-composite", area_file, plot_file, "( -blur 1x65000 )", mask_file, out_file)
    }       
    system(cmd)
}
```

Ejemplo de uso:

```
ibrary(datasets)
library(ggplot2)

rm(list = ls())

area_img_file <- file.path(getwd(),"dolar.jpg")
out_file <- file.path(getwd(), "final.png")
imgmagick_path <- NA

# Genero la grafica
plot1 <- ggplot(airquality, aes(x = Ozone)) +
    geom_density(fill = "#4271AE", colour = "#CC6666", alpha = 1) +
    scale_x_continuous(name = "Promedio de Ozono en\npartes por billones",
                       breaks = seq(0, 200, 25),
                       limits=c(0, 200)) +
    scale_y_continuous(name = "Density") +
    ggtitle("Gráfico de densidad del promedio de ozono")

plot2 <- plot1 + geom_density(fill = "#CC6666", colour = "#CC6666", alpha = 1)

add_image_to_color(imgmagick_path, area_img_file, out_file, plot1, plot2)
```

Lo interesante de esta técnica, es que la puedes aplicar a cualquier tipo de gráfico, el procedimiento inicial es el mismo, generar dos versiones del mismo `plot` dónde únicamente difiere el color a enmascarar. Por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o también:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Edición del 06/01/2018

Solo era cuestión de tiempo para que alguien preparara esta funcionalidad. Hace tres días fue el commit inicial de [ggwithimages](https://github.com/gsimchoni/ggwithimages) de Giora Simchoni que resuelve bastante bien la pregunta. Para poder usar este paquete directamente de el repositorio, en primer lugar hay que instalar [devtools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/index.html)

```
install.package("devtools")
```

Luego:

```
devtools::install_github("gsimchoni/ggwithimages")
```

Este paquete actualmente ofrece dos funciones `geom_line_with_image()` y `geom_hist_with_image()`, lo que permite agregar fácilmente imágenes a gráficos de lineas e histogramas, lamentablemente no para áreas ni otro tipo de gráfico, pero no debiera ser demasiado complicado adaptarlo. Ejemplo de uso:

```
dolar <- png::readPNG("dolar.png")
ggplot(BOD, aes(x=Time, y=demand)) + geom_line_with_image(dolar, lineColor=2, lineWidth = 2)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Crack, muy buena esa!

Comment: No funciona, he intentado realizarlo tal como muestra el ejemplo pero no lo conseguí. Tengo instalado R versión 3.5.1

Comment: @user95892, y por que no publicas una pregunta con más información, por ejemplo los errores y warnings que tuvieras así podemos ayudarte.